# How to get Memory Bank User Data when performing Inventory in Zebra RFID Android?

Tags: android, rfid

While the RFID API application allows you to perform an Inventory after selecting which memory bank to access, I can't seem to allow any similar functionality in my application, I'd like to know how to do this, as, right now, tag.getMemoryBankData() just returns "null", despite me knowing that there is data in the Tag

I've tried searching documentation, and the Zebra Techdocs for some kind of configuration option that lets me access this as well. I've tried extracting the code from the RFID API .apk to try and see how it's done, but it's too obfuscated, and I can't find it.

This is my trigger and antenna configuration, if it helps.

```java
TriggerInfo triggerInfo = new TriggerInfo();
            triggerInfo.StartTrigger.setTriggerType(START_TRIGGER_TYPE.START_TRIGGER_TYPE_IMMEDIATE);
            triggerInfo.StopTrigger.setTriggerType(STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE.STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE_IMMEDIATE);
            try {
                // receive events from reader
                if (eventHandler == null)
                    eventHandler = new EventHandler();
                reader.Events.addEventsListener(eventHandler);
                // HH event
                reader.Events.setHandheldEvent(true);
                // tag event with tag data
                reader.Events.setTagReadEvent(true);
                reader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(false);
                // set trigger mode as rfid so scanner beam will not come
                reader.Config.setTriggerMode(ENUM_TRIGGER_MODE.RFID_MODE, true);
                // set start and stop triggers
                reader.Config.setStartTrigger(triggerInfo.StartTrigger);
                reader.Config.setStopTrigger(triggerInfo.StopTrigger);
                reader.Config.setUniqueTagReport(true);

                // power levels are index based so maximum power supported get the last one
                MAX_POWER = reader.ReaderCapabilities.getTransmitPowerLevelValues().length - 1;
                // set antenna configurations
                Antennas.AntennaRfConfig config = reader.Config.Antennas.getAntennaRfConfig(1);
                config.setTransmitPowerIndex(MAX_POWER);
                config.setrfModeTableIndex(0);
                config.setTari(0);
                reader.Config.setDPOState(DYNAMIC_POWER_OPTIMIZATION.DISABLE);
                reader.Config.setAccessOperationWaitTimeout(500);
                reader.Config.Antennas.setAntennaRfConfig(1, config);
                // Set the singulation control
                Antennas.SingulationControl s1_singulationControl = reader.Config.Antennas.getSingulationControl(1);
                s1_singulationControl.setSession(SESSION.SESSION_S0);
                s1_singulationControl.Action.setInventoryState(INVENTORY_STATE.INVENTORY_STATE_A);
                s1_singulationControl.Action.setSLFlag(SL_FLAG.SL_ALL);
                reader.Config.Antennas.setSingulationControl(1, s1_singulationControl);
                // delete any prefilters
                reader.Actions.PreFilters.deleteAll();
                //
            } catch (InvalidUsageException | OperationFailureException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I keep expecting to obtain the MEMORY_BANK_USER data but it returns "null" always, and while I know there's a way to obtain it without having to do a Read operation, I can't seem to find how to. If anyone can help with this, I'd be eternally grateful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To read the MEMORY_BANK_USER content use the tag access mode

```
rfidreader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(true);
```

and the code for the event handler

```
class EventHandler implements RfidEventsListener {
  // Read Event Notification
  public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e) {
    TagData tag = e.getReadEventData().tagData;
    if (tag.getOpCode() == ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.ACCESS_OPERATION_READ 
         && tag.getOpStatus() == ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS.ACCESS_SUCCESS) {
      Log.d(TAG, "eventReadNotify - tag id " + tag.getTagID() + " and mem bank " + tag.getMemoryBankData());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Right now I do not have my RFID reader with me ATM, when I do, I will be sure to test this and mark your answer as correct, if it works, and I'm sure it will. (I'll delete this comment as well)